# Stop spacebar keypress from triggering autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

<sub>**Update**</sub>

<sub>This was fixed in Eclipse **2018-12**. This behaviour is still default, but can be configured off - see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876787/1082449) for how</sub>

<sub>I'll leave the question as it was for posterity, and for those on earlier versions of Eclipse</sub>

---

In Eclipse, I've enabled intellisense-style suggestions for Java by going to

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist
```

and setting the following

```
Auto activation delay (ms) -> 0
Auto activation triggers for Java -> .(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

*source = [Eclipse Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943131/eclipse-intellisense)*

This works brilliantly, apart from one annoying problem. When I hit <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, the token being typed is autocompleted with whatever is at the top of the suggestions list. Fair enough, except that sometimes I'll type a class/variable name with an exact legal match, but this *won't* appear as the top suggestion. So when I naturally hit <kbd>spacebar</kbd> Eclipse inserts something completely wrong.

> **E.G.** after typing `Cookie` I'll hit <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and get `CookieMonster`.

This seems like a bug, and happens often enough to be annoying, but even despite this **I don't want <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to trigger autocomplete in general**. I may want to type a variable name which hasn't been declared yet, or something similar. I want to use autocomplete as a helper tool, but my natural typing should *always* take priority over it.

I'd like to stop <kbd>spacebar</kbd> triggering autocomplete, and either fall back to using <kbd>enter</kbd>, or better still trigger autocomplete with a <kbd>custom</kbd> key not used in ordinary typing. **Is any of this possible?**

I've played around with all the settings in *Content Assist* to no avail. Googling the question just returns a bunch of results about disabling the autocomplete feature.

---

**This issue is fixed from Eclipse 2018-12 [4.10]** see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876787/1082449)

It's present in all prior versions, i.e. *2018-09* [4.9], *Photon* [4.8], *Oxygen* [4.7], *Neon* [4.6], etc..

Comment: +1 I was just fighting with that very same problem... any luck on solving this? It is very annoying to press space and get something that you did not want (you did not select it!)... This may be good for "Type declaration", but for "variable names" is not reasonable.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Do you know if the same problem exists in the latest version Kepler (4.3)? I haven't upgraded yet but if so I will update the question

Comment: Unfortunately that very same behavior takes place in Kepler (4.3)... It is really a pity. I like a lot that auto activation but it is really annoying having it making such a selection in several situations. My temporary solution is to increase slightly the activation time, so that I write most of the new variable name... but this does not work always. I will research a bit further this issue, and probably be reporting this to Eclipse, since I do think it is a bug not a feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371618/validate-autocomplete-in-eclipse  (indicating that Indigo also already behaved like this)

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759855/eclipse-instant-autocompletion

Comment: Judging by the number of up votes on this question, and the lack of up votes on answers, it looks like Eclipse needs to fix this!

Comment: Agreed that this is INCREDIBLY annoying! Didn't bother me until I tried PyCharm (probably the same in IntelliJ). They display autocomplete suggestions instantly but only "accept" suggestions with the Tab key and it seems like a perfect solution.

Comment: FYI, I just whipped up a plug-in real quick (below in @AndrewXu's answer about writing plug-ins) that changes the behavior in Eclipse Luna to only accept Tab and Enter as intelli-sense completion keys.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Eclipse 2018-12 was already patched for this!

A patch for [Bug 348857](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348857) was recently merged to the Eclipse project and was released as part of **Eclipse 2018-12**. You can download that version [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/r).

You now have a new option to disable all insertion triggers apart from <kbd>enter</kbd>, which will prevent <kbd>spacebar</kbd> from causing autocompletion.

Simply go to *Preferences...* -> *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Content Assist* (or *Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Editor* -> *Content Assist* on Windows) and select ***Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'***, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: Disable insertion triggers preferences]

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. I added heading to your answer so people see clearly it's for the current versions. Other answers are outdated.

Comment: @Pyves It took me a while to accepting this newer answer, apologies, but I don't use Eclipse any more and didn't get round to verifying it. Anyway, yes, this looks like it definitively solves the problem and I'm really glad it *was* solved more than 6 years on!

Comment: Anyone getting a problem where the trigger suppression is not working inside the Debug Shell view? For me spacebar is triggering autocomplete. (I am on June 2019)

Comment: @William Dutton possibly something to flag up in a separate bug report.

Answer (score 26):

There is a solution [on the issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348857#attach_236956) for this. 
Copy the [jar](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=236956) in the eclipse/dropins folder. With the next restart space is diabled as autocompletion trigger.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348857

**Eclipse 12-2018 and newer:** This is working natively, check Pyves answer.

Comment: Looks awesome but.. it doesn't work for me in Eclipse Juno - no change in behaviour, spacebar still activates the autocomplete. Is this working for you in Kepler? Where are the toolbar button/menu items for toggling the tool mentioned in the bug thread?

Comment: Yes, works for me in Kepler Service Release 1. However I don't see the toolbar items either.

Comment: This does not work for me in Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2 -- Build Id: 20150219-0600).

Comment: I just whipped up a plug-in real quick (below in @AndrewXu's answer about writing plug-ins) that changes the behavior in Eclipse Luna to only accept Tab and Enter as intelli-sense completion keys.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8.1 with Luna SR2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600.

Comment: This now works for me, with a Mac running OSX Yosemite, with Luna 4.4.0 Build 20140612-0600. Excellent!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to not work with java type proposals but other proposals seems to work correctly. (Luna 64bit version)

Comment: Worked on kepler. Thank you so much. Autocomplete with space bar is so annoying!

Comment: this worked for me in ecipse mars too, you need to restart the eclipse again to take the jar loading correctly.

Comment: Works in neon, too. Thankfully.

Comment: Odexious - how did you get it to work in Neon? When I drop it in it doesn't work and I get internal errors.

Comment: @Pascalius thank you for your answer which for a long time was the best one, but now Eclipse has fixed this and made it configurable natively. This is pointed out in a newer answer, so I've accepted that one instead as it's now the best way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Use a SDK version of eclipse

1.open Plug-ins View and find org.eclipse.jface.text, right click, choose import as Source Project. After import, you find it in your workspace.

2.In src/org/eclipse/jface/text/contentassist/CompletionProposalPopup.java

```
char[] triggers = t.getTriggerCharacter();
if(contains(triggers,key))
```

change to

```
if(key!='='&&key!=0x20&&contains(triggers,key))
```

3.Export org.eclipse.jface.text

Right click the project folder of org.eclipse.jface.text, choose export-->Deployable plugins and fragments, next, destination choose archive file, finish. Replace the one in eclipse/plugins with the one you generate.

Comment: For those wondering how to open this view, go to "Window"->"Show View"->"Other..." and in the filter text box start typing "plug" and then select "Plug-ins" from the box below and press "OK".

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a more Visual Studio like experience, I recommend just commenting out that block entirely (the default block), commenting out the '\t' block, and then finding the block that handles '\r' and '\n' (right above those two), and adding '\t' to it. -- This will give you tab completion. :-)

Comment: (For those that don't want to go through all this trouble, here's mine for the 64-bit version of Eclipse Luna SR2 4.4.2: http://1drv.ms/1GZhJPq -- keep in mind the changes I mentioned above.)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 If you could a) post the code to github or b) add "." to completion triggers, that would be awesome.

Comment: Why did you use `0x20` instead of `' '`?

Comment: You are a God-send.  I wish I could favorite answers

Answer (score 3):

The spacebar has been a key to select the autocomplete even in Indigo.  To my knowledge, this can't be configured.
In fact, that is probably why the delay exists.

I suggest setting the delay to some optimal value that allows you to type things like `private void ...` comfortably without triggering suggestions for `private` and `void`.  Then in case you get a suggestion because you waited too long, press Escape to abort Content Assist.

Comment: I've had only limited success from increasing the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Same configuration as davnicwil, same issue, still on eclipse 4.4.

**Solution**: Intercept (hook) SHIFT+SPACE (press and hold) on (editor-window) eclipse and replace it with ESC,SPACE (sequence). Now you my decide between

- Autocomplete+SPACE: press SPACE when autosuggestion present
- just SPACE: press predefined key combination or sequence (e.g. SHIFT+SPACE)

On windows you may use http://www.heise.de/download/activaid.html (you can also use AutoHotkey, java native hook, ...)

HowTo with ActivAid:

1. Open Ac'tivAid, select "UserHotkeys"
2. click on "+", set a description
3. click on "short cut", press e.g. SHIFT+SPACE
4. Command: "{ESC}{SPACE}" (without quotes)
5. click "+", select eclipse editor frame, press ENTER
6. click OK, OK in Ac'tivAid

My config file:activAid/settings/ac'tivAid.ini:[UserHotkeys]

```
Hotkey11=+Space
Path11=<Send>{ESC}{SPACE}
Description11=Eclipse Shift+Space -> Esc,Space
Category11=
Application11=ahk_class SWT_Window0
```

You may also remap keys on non-english keyboards with "HotStrings", e.g. ö->{,ä->} etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out.

Try download this [org.eclipse.jface.text.jar](http://goo.gl/SI5JyN) and copy it to your plugin folder(Typically eclipse/plugin). Do not forget to backup your own one.

Works on Eclipse Juno.

If the link doesn't work, comment on this, thanks.

Comment: MARS1 Eclipse could not be started, java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry.

Answer (score -3):

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys and remove the binding for the command Content Assist.

Comment: That would remove the possibility to bring up the suggestions using ctrl+Space.  What the OP wants is a way to disable selection of a suggestion using the spacebar.  No key binding exists for that.

Answer (score -4):

You could disable Auto activation via the check box in

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java/Editor/Content Assist
```

and activate the auto-complete feature on demand. The default hotkey for this is

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: The whole problem is that I *want* the auto activation behaviour, just without spacebar doing the autocomplete