# How to disable Non-Type proposals in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

My auto activation keys are set to a to z. Thus once I type <kbd>str</kbd>, it proposes `StringBuilder`, which is what I want.

[image: Eclipse show Java Type proposals]

Then, I press <kbd>Space</kbd> to accept the suggestion, and type <kbd>sb</kbd> for the variable name. Eclipse shows Non-Type proposals "sBuilder". Since I have decided the variable name to be `sb`, the Non-Type proposals are useless.

[image: Eclipse show Java Non-Type proposals]

As the annoying proposal shows, I cannot continue to type <kbd>=</kbd>, because Eclipse will change my variable name from `sb` to `sBuilder`. So I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>=</kbd>.

Every time I define variables, Eclipse always gives me Non-Type proposals, which costs one <kbd>Esc</kbd> to reject. How to disable Non-Type proposals in Eclipse??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop spacebar keypress from triggering autocomplete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Open `Window - Preferences`.
2. Go to `Java - Editor - Content Assists - Advanced`.
3. In Advanced page, the `Java Proposals` should be checked by default. `Java Proposals` consists of both `Non-type` and `Type proposals`.
4. If you want to disable `Non Type Proposal`, uncheck the `Java Proposals` and `Java Non-Type Proposals`, then check the `Java Type Proposals`.

Comment: Should also uncheck Java Proposals (Task-Focused). Thank you!

Comment: Really? It doesn't work as your post says untill I unchecked Java Proposals (Task-Focused).

Comment: Sorry, I just check again my eclipse setting. Yes you must uncheck that..:)

Comment: If you want still show defined variables, set Content assist cycling, check the `Java Non-Type Proposals`. Then you must press `CTRL+SPACE` repeatedly to find your variables..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get what you want is to change your workflow a tiny bit: Type "new Str" instead of "Str" only, let Eclipse auto complete this to "new StringBuilder()", hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> to automatically create an assignment to a local variable *in front of the constructor* and just type the name as you want it.

That's less keystrokes and less choices presented by code completion.

Answer (score 0):

This question may provide what you want a solution in another form: [Stop spacebar keypress from triggering autocomplete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse)

The answers here provides a means for the autocompletion to not interfere with the typing eliminating the problem. I personally have my eclipse set up to trigger autocomplete on every character typed but then have it say (Via source editing) to only have the enter key accept. This allows you for only accepting autocompletion when you want to.