# Stop Eclipse from autocompleting variable names on declaration

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Edit: I am a dumbass who repeatedly went into CA for JavaScript instead of Java. This is what happens when you blindly use the search box, folks.

I know this question has been asked and answered here before, but there's a problem. The solution just *isn't there anymore*.

I have the exact same problem as [this good fella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse). I saw the answers, they say it's been patched in the 2018-12 release, which I assume is about 18 months old (I've only recently started using eclipse). I'm on the 2020-03 release and, as I said, the `Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'` just isn't there anymore. See below:

Eclipse Preferences->Editor->Content Assist Window in 2020-03 release:

[image: Eclipse Preferences->Editor->Content Assist Window in 2020-03 release]

I tried looking for it elsewhere in Preferences but I can't find it. When I try to google it all that comes is this same solution, and nothing useful comes up if I filter the searches for time. Does someone know where this option went or if there is another way I can fix this? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the Content Assist preference page I see on my 2020-03 Eclipse which does include the Disable insertion triggers option. Are you sure you are running 2020-03 - what does Help > About say?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I checked before posting. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/ezv1ea5) the about page. I'm thoroughly confused. Why would they take away an apparently perfectly functioning feature?

Comment: it is something with your eclipse. I have 2020-03 and it has that option under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assistant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your screenshot shows** the **JavaScript**, not the Java **content assist** preference page where this setting has never existed:

*Window* (macOS: *Eclipse*) *> Prefences: **JavaScript** > Editor > Content Assist*

The **Java content assist setting** described in the mentioned answer can still be found at the same place:

*Window* (macOS: *Eclipse*) *> Prefences: **Java** > Editor > Content Assist*

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I feel like an idiot. I didn't check where I was when I got to the CA through search. Several times. Thanks dude.